How to bind L-click to keybind, but only when not typing (in AHK)?
I am a total AHK newbie. I just recently discovered the joy of being able to click by binding L-click to a keyboard key. I bound it to my letter "D" key, however I then ran into what should have been an obvious problem of now not being able to type the letter "D" at all. The script I am using is just:
D::LButton
Whenever I try to type "D", it just clicks wherever my mouse is.
Is there a way to bind L-click to my D key, but have it **NOT **trigger when pressing "D" in a typing field (e.g. the URL bar, or when a cell in Google Sheets is double-clicked, or when you press Enter to type in a video game, etc)? I basically want to be able to type "D" when a typing field is focused, while being able to L-click with "D" (i.e. trigger the script) when a typing field is not focused.
If someone could lend some advice, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you

I can pretty much guarantee there is no way you can make this work flawlessly. As you can see from the one answer this question has, there is something you can do about this, but you can't always accurately tell when you're on some input field that wants input, and when not. If you only use this script part time, I guess then some half solution like that can work for you. But if you want to use a script like this 247, I'd recommend you instead bind something not so commonly used, or maybe have some quick hotkey to toggle your remap on/off.

AHK v1:
The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings:
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#If (A_Cursor != "IBeam") ; the mouse pointer is not in text input mode

    d::LButton
    
#If

AHK v2:
The #HotIf directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf (A_Cursor != "IBeam")

    d::LButton
    
#HotIf

